# extract browser language rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This method extract browser language and is working fine when the language have 2 letter, `es, en, de`...etc.

```
  def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    browser_locale = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].try(:scan, /^[a-z]{2}/).try(:first).try(:to_sym) 
    if I18n.available_locales.include? browser_locale
      browser_locale
    else
      I18n.default_locale
    end
  end
```

However is not working when the browser language have 4 letters:

```
en
en-us
en-gb
en-au
en-ca
zh-TW
zh-cn
```

**How can fix this problem?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is only looking for two letters try this:

```
browser_locale = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].try(:scan, /^[a-z-]{2,5}/).try(:first).try(:to_sym)
```

This will work with two to five character codes with lower case letters or dashes.

This is just a start you may need to refine this regular expression more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [ruby gem](https://github.com/ioquatix/http-accept) which does exactly what you want:

```
languages = HTTP::Accept::Language.parse("da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7")

expect(languages[0].locale).to be == "da"
expect(languages[1].locale).to be == "en-gb"
expect(languages[2].locale).to be == "en"
```

It has 100% test coverage on a wide range of inputs.